# Floating box is pushing everything else down - infinite scrolling

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

So I add the box called "booking-picker" which is supposed to scroll down with you on the page -- but it pushes all the elements that are below him whatever they are.
FYI bootstrap used. 
http://jsfiddle.net/2m849oes/
or
Here is the script:

```
    <script>
    $(function() {

        var $sidebar   = $("#flow-picker"), 
            $window    = $(window),
            offset     = $sidebar.offset(),
            topPadding = 15

        $window.scroll(function() {
            if ($window.scrollTop() > offset.top) {
                $sidebar.stop().animate({
                    marginTop: $window.scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
                });
            } else {
                $sidebar.stop().animate({
                    marginTop: 0
                });
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

And here is the html:

```
<div class="container">  
    <div class="row">BLABLABLABLABLA ........ 
    </div>
    <div class="booking-picker" id="flow-picker">
        <h3>Hello</h3>
        ETC......                    
    </div>    
</div>
```

And later I have the footer which is pushed down too.

And here is the CSS

```
.booking-picker {
  display: block;
  float: right;
}
#flow-picker {

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You have too much closing div tags. It's just here or also in your code?

Comment: Can we have a fiddle? - sounds dirty, but I hope you know what I mean.

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by fiddle?

Comment: @commandantp a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that shows your problem in action. However, I think you need to use `fixed` position as mentioned. When you use fixed remember to specify a `height` and a `width`, also you will need to use 'top' not `margin-top`. But depends on what you're after, which is why a fiddle would help to show us :)

Comment: @DavidT Thanks for helping. I did try the fixed but even if I specifiy a hight and width it disappears...

Comment: @DavidT There you go! http://jsfiddle.net/2m849oes/
FYI: in the fiddle it doesn't scroll down forever but in my page yes. Also no idea why it floats left instead of right even thought it says right...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used your fiddle from the question and updated it slightly for you [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2m849oes/1/). what I have done is added some css to `#flow-picker` see below

```
#flow-picker {
    position: fixed;
    top: 20px;
    right: 0;
    background: blue;
    color: white;
}
```

The background colour is just so you can see what is going on. When you use `fixed` position you need to specify a position using `top`, `bottom`, `left` and/or `right` properties. This tells the browser where to place it. They will be placed relative to the browser window.

I removed your javascript because if this is what you are trying to achieve you can do it without javascript. Its normally better to try and use pure CSS for when it can be done using only CSS.

I have made [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5stcrkpb/1/) which i have coloured to help show you how it works.

Comment: Thank you very much!! It works now, scrolling strangely - meaning udge setps on my screen - but i think I can tweak that in the js. 
Quick one thought, why was that not working on the .booking-picker element and it works with the id #flow-picker?

Comment: @commandantp when you used `float` your element was still in the 'flow' of the DOM, which means that other elements positions are affected by `.date-picker` by using `position: fixed` you're taking the element out of the natural flow of the DOM. So it wont :)

Comment: Ummm OK! In my app I had to keep the js and put the position to absolute with all the other stuff you said, and now I get exactly what I need! Still very new at all this so thank you for your patience and help ;)

Answer (score 0):

I believe it needs an absolute or fixed position...

Comment: Fixed would be better I think.

Comment: Whenever I use fixed, the whole element disappears from the page... :/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a jsfiddle

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/macsupport/2m849oes/4/)

```
.booking-picker {
position:fixed;
right:5px;
display: block;
background:red;
}
```